# What kind visa do I need for USA travel to participate in a research conference being an Indian citizen?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, f1-visas

I am an Indian citizen. I am a PhD scholar and I want to participate in a 5 days research conference in the USA. I am not aware of what kind of visa category I will need. I heard about F1 Visa or J1 visa or B1 visa. But not sure which would be appropriate for me. How to apply for a B1/F1/J1 Visa?

Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: For conferences B1/B2 visa should be fine. I don't have experience applying. Let the experienced people reply here.

Comment: @AnishSheela, thank you

Comment: You need a B1/B2 visa for that. If you live in India, the wait time for US visa appointments is currently around 3 years.

Comment: @ThomasCruise, you mean there is no appointments now. I am living in India.  I think there will some way by  directly mailing to visa consulate

Comment: @MAS You can mail the consulate. That is how those with urgent travel, like students (F-1), workers (H1B), etc are getting earlier appointments. If the consulates is convinced of the urgency of travel (which I doubt in case of a conference), they can provide an earlier appointment. A lot of people were also able to get earlier appointments by booking an appointment first and then constantly checking for any opened up slots due to cancelation and grabbing them. You can check the wait time here: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html

Comment: @ThomasCruise, thanks a lot. This idea worked few months ago for my schengen visa, which was also for research conference